# I need to add sorting to a table created from an array by clicking buttons, sorting can be by name, ID or age

Tags: javascript, html

> I created a table and a list of button clicks and tried to create a
> sort, but   i burned out
> I tried to sort using function(a, b) but it didn't work

```js
var massiv = {
  'Andrey': 
  [
    ['Возраст: ', 19],
    ['IDentificator: ', '#333']
  ],
  'Random': 
  [
    ['Возраст: ', 1489],
    ['IDentificator: ', '#111']
  ],
  'FcScript': 
  [
    ['Возраст: ', 189],
    ['IDentificator: ', '#445']
  ],
  'Ampere': 
  [
    ['Возраст: ', 159],
    ['IDentificator: ', '#654']
  ],
  'Gerc': 
  [
    ['Возраст: ', 5519],
    ['IDentificator: ', '#0-9-97']
  ],
  'NotAndrey': 
  [
    ['Возраст: ', 23419],
    ['IDentificator: ', '#-63i4k']
  ],
}
const father = document.querySelector('.divide').innerHTML = `<table class='tabl'></table>`;
const plus = document.querySelector('#plus');
const minus = document.querySelector('#minus');
for (key in massiv) {
let around = document.createElement('tr');

around.innerHTML = `<td colspan='2'>${key}</td>`

document.querySelector('.tabl').appendChild(around)

  for (let x = 0; x<massiv[key].length; x ++){
  let row = document.createElement('tr');

  row.innerHTML = `
    <td>${massiv[key][x][0]}</td>
    <td>${massiv[key][x][1]}</td>
  `
  plus.addEventListener('click', function (a, b) {
    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>${massiv[key][x][0]}</td>
    <td></td>
  `
  })
  document.querySelector('.tabl').appendChild(row);
}}
```

```css
.tabl {
    border: 3px solid rgb(126, 126, 126);
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.tabl > th
.tabl > td {
    border: 2px solid rgb(126, 126, 126);
}
.tabl > tr {
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
 
     <ul id="column" class="book__list">
     
       </ul>
       <ul id="plan">
<div class="divide">

</div>
<button id="plus">Sort +</button>
<button id="minus">Sort -</button>
       <script src="badscript.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

at the same time, I was able to sort the array and output it to the consoleat the same time, I was able to sort the array and output it to the consoleat the same time, I was able to sort the array and output it to the console